# Duda con Breakpoints CSS

Tags: css, html5, css3

Ultimamente estoy trabajando bastante con librerias como [parallax.js](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) y [wow.js](https://wowjs.uk/) entonces he usado varios (demasiados quizás) elementos flotantes para posteriormente aplicar algun efecto de movimiento.

Entiendo que los breakpoints que maneja Bootstrap son:

```
<style>
    /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 576px) {}

    /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {}

    /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {}

    /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {}
    
    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {}
    /* Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px) */
    
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {}
    /* Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px) */
    
    @media (max-width: 991.98px) {}
    /* Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px) */
    
    @media (max-width: 1199.98px) {}
</style>
```

Mi problema es que cuando tengo una estructura parecida a lo siguiente, ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document SOes</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <a href="">
            <img src="{{url('assets/element/element.png')}}" alt="" class="moveStackOverF">
        </a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Y tengo en mi hoja de estilo por ejemplo:

```
<style>
    .moveStackOverF{
        position: relative;
        top: 10%;
        left: 5%;
        width: 50%
    }
</style>
```

Tengo que estar considerando en cada uno de los `Breakpoints` el `Height` de la pantalla porque al tener un `top` en porcentaje mi elemento se sale del `body` cuando este se hace mas pequeño.

Como puedo solucionar ese problema?

Por que' los `Breakpoints` consideran el `width` pero no toman el `height` ?

Siempre he tenido ese problema cuando quiero hacer un sitio responsivo.
Agradezco cualquier comentario,

Comment: No uses tanto breakpoints,  usa solo los primeros 4.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la propiedad `hidden` si lo que quieres es que no se salga del `body`
eso si lo que quieres es que se muestre solo un determinado valor de `height`

```css
    
    body{
      height:100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container{
        background: teal;
        height:120%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document SOes</title>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <a href="">
            <img src="{{url('assets/element/element.png')}}" alt="" class="moveStackOverF">
        </a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```